# Количество скрола в jquery чтоли?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте всем, во общем такой вопрос: алерт должен появляться через две прокрутки.

```
$(windows).scroll(function(){
//куда и как прикрутить гугл не дал ответа
  alert('Алерт');
});
```

Никто не знает как это делается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получаем начальную позицию.
Получаем высоту окна браузера.

Сравниваем: Если (данная высота - (минус) начальная высота) больше чем две высоты окна браузера, то выполнятся условие.

```
var startTop = $(this).scrollTop();
var window_height = $.browser.opera? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();

$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    if($(this).scrollTop() - startTop > window_height*2) {
        alert(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Очень интересное решение, че то ошибка 
ReferenceError: getViewportHeight is not defined
[Прерывать на этой ошибке]  

...compatMode != 'CSS1Compat' ? document.body.scrollHeight : document.documentEleme...

Comment: @bemulima  Обновил.